# How to make a 3d plot in Simulink from real-time (x, y, z) coordinates?

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot, simulink

I am building a project to take as input z coordinates of the roof from a distance sensor mounted on a robot via arduino and take the x and y from two rotary encoders. I have used the Simulink Support Package for Arduino to take digital inputs.

Currently I am not using the encoders and so I'll be storing X and Y coordinates in a matrix and use those for plotting.

I now plan to plot the z-coordinates with pre-defined X and Y coordinates onto a 3d Plot and I am not able to understand how to proceed.

As the readings of z-coordinates is real-time, I hope to get a real-time varying 3d plot. Alternatively, I can also store a set of 1000 points and then plot those and then clear the memory for the next 1000 points.

Thing is, the plot is going to be a line that has its points scattered over the x and y axes.

Kindly advise how to obtain the plot in Simulink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built in 3d plot block for simulink (at least up to the version I used actively), but you can find some code for different blocks in the file exchange. Two examples:

https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/61335-3d-stem-for-simulink-block
https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4915-3dscope

Pick the one you like or look for further ones.

Comment: I tried the first one before too. Problem is that there is no way of zooming or changing the viewing angle as in normal stem3 plots.

Comment: plot3 doesnt work in Simulink. (via MATLAB Function)

Comment: In your previous comment you asked for MATLAB, not for Simulink. That is what I answered. For an example in Simulink, look at the examples above. At least one explains how to use `plot3`.